# getopt_long()'s longindex always 0

Tags: c, getopt-long

In a C program I have to parse command line option for which I am using C function getopt_long() whose syntax is:

```
int getopt_long(int argc, char * const *argv, const char *optstring, const struct option *longopts, int *longindex);
```

Problem is I always receive the value of last parameter longindex as 0.

Below is the sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

static int verbose_flag;

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int c;

printf("MAIN\n");
    int i;
    printf("argc = %d\n",argc);
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n",i, argv[i]);
    }

  while (1)
    {
      static struct option long_options[] =
        {
          {"delete",  required_argument, 0, 'd'},
          {"create",  required_argument, 0, 'c'},
          {"file",    required_argument, 0, 'f'},
          {0, 0, 0, 0}
        };

      int option_index = 0;    
      c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "c:d:f:",
                       long_options, &option_index);
    printf("\nOPT c = %d, option_index = %d START\n", c, option_index);

      if (c == -1)
      {
          printf("BREAKKKKKKKKKKK\n");
        break;
        }

      printf("OPTION FOUND c = %d, option_index = %d, long_options[option_index].name = %s\n", c, option_index, long_options[option_index].name);
      switch (c)
        {
        case 0:
          if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
            break;
          printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
          if (optarg)
            printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
          printf ("\n");
          break;

        case 'c':
          printf ("option -c with value `%s'\n", optarg);
          break;

        case 'd':
          printf ("option -d with value `%s'\n", optarg);
          break;

        case 'f':
          printf ("option -f with value `%s'\n", optarg);
          break;

        case '?':
          break;

        default:
          abort ();
        }
    }

  if (verbose_flag)
    puts ("verbose flag is set");

  if (optind < argc)
    {
      printf ("non-option ARGV-elements: ");
      while (optind < argc)
        printf ("%s ", argv[optind++]);
      putchar ('\n');
    }

  return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
MAIN
argc = 5
argv[0] = /home/a.out
argv[1] = -delete
argv[2] = dell
argv[3] = -create
argv[4] = ceat

OPT c = 100, option_index = 0 START
OPTION FOUND c = 100, option_index = 0, long_options[option_index].name = delete
option -d with value `elete'

OPT c = 99, option_index = 0 START
OPTION FOUND c = 99, option_index = 0, long_options[option_index].name = delete
option -c with value `reate'

OPT c = -1, option_index = 0 START
BREAKKKKKKKKKKK
non-option ARGV-elements: dell ceat
```

Am I missing something?
Why do I always the value of last parameter longindex as 0?
How to rectify the issue?

Comment: For the arguments you provided, what is the *expected* output?

Comment: Look like you're invoking your program with arguments like `-delete` instead of `--delete` for some reason?

Comment: Correct Shawn. That was the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `argv[…] = …` output it seems like you’re using long options incorrectly. Rather than invoke your program like this

```
/home/a.out -delete dell -create creat
```

Invoke it like this:

```
/home/a.out --delete dell --create creat
```

This will cause the index to be set correctly.

Check the [`getopt_long(3)` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long), section “Description”, for details on how to use long options.

Comment: One more problem I am facing.
Short option with single - does not work and option index always returns 0.
I have to use -- to get the short options working.
I mean I have to use --d dell --c ceat
Should not short option work with one -?